# innerJoin Query in Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I mysql query :

```
SELECT p.name, c.id 
FROM customer c  
INNER JOIN sales_order so ON so.customer_id=c.id  
INNER JOIN sales_order_item soi ON so.id=soi.sales_order_id  
INNER JOIN product p ON p.id=soi.product_id  WHERE c.id=49454\G;
```

this is working in MySql but when this query convert in doctrine2 then it's given error

```
"[Semantical Error] line 0, col 87 near 'so ON so.customer_id=c.id': Error: Identification Variable sales_order used in join path expression but was not defined before."
```

In symfony form I write this:

```
$builder
        ->add('filter', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Show',
            'class' => 'RocketBraPrintBundle:SalesOrderItem',
            'query_builder' => function($er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('p','so','c','soi')
                          ->select('p.name','c.id')
                          ->from('customer','c')
                          ->innerJoin('sales_order','so','ON','so.customer_id=c.id')
                          ->innerJoin('sales_order_item','soi','ON','so.id=soi.sales_order_id')
                          ->innerJoin('product','p', 'ON', 'p.id=soi.product_id')
                          ->where('c.id=49454\G');
            },
            'empty_value' => 'All',
            'required' => false
        ))
```

Can any one tell me what is right way to convert this mysql query in symfony2 way ?

Answer (score 0):

```
->innerJoin('c.sales_order')
```

where "sales_order" is the exact relation name from "customer" entity.

Comment: Thanks for reply ,I write this bt i got again error "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 92 near 'soi ON soi.sales_order_item=soi.id': Error: Identification Variable sales_order_item used in join path expression but was not defined before."

Comment: sales_order - this needs to be the exact relation name as it appears in your entity class. NOT the database table name. I put sales_order cause i thought that's the name you used.

Answer (score 0):

it is complicated for me because i have bit confuse and It's convert like this.It's working.if user logedIn.

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('soi')
   ->select('soi','p','so')
   ->innerJoin('soi.salesOrder', 'so')
   ->innerJoin('soi.product', 'p')
   ->innerJoin('so.customer', 'c')
   ->groupBy('p.name')
   ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC')
   ->where('so.customer = ' . $options['data']['customerid']);
```